# How to setup SVN on live Magento site on Shared Hosting

Tags: svn, magento, installation

I've got a live magento store running. I've determined that I definitely need to learn and use SVN immediately. My hosting (Hostgator) only supports the client, not repos with my package. I am going to be the only developer for the longevity of this owning this store (as far as I know).

I do not want to pay a separate repo hosting fee and am ok with hosting a repo locally on my dev machine. In your experiences, what is my best plan of attack from this point? My goals are:

1. Be able to host a dev site (dev.domain.com).
2. Work locally on files and commit them to dev site for testing.
3. Publish dev files to live environment.

I've just began reading on basics of SVN so be gently with me :) Thanks!

Comment: check this out [Magento Development and Deployment](http://www.aschroder.com/2011/02/magento-development-and-deployment-setting-up-a-modman-based-magento-project-on-magento-1-5/)

Comment: xp-dev.com offers a free svn hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Magento Development and Deployment](http://www.aschroder.com/2011/02/magento-development-and-deployment-setting-up-a-modman-based-magento-project-on-magento-1-5/) post that Oğuz Çelikdemir points out is a good one for sure.

The other thing to be aware of is that your svn repository will need to be accessible to both your local development environment, and your dev/production sites.  Unless you set up a port forward or similar to your dev machine this might mean you'll need to pay for svn repository hosting somewhere.

Also, for learning svn, the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) book is very good.

Comment: I think I'm on the right path here with the article that Oğuz suggested.  I decided I can host my own SVN server because our startup budget cannot afford more monthly fees.  I've got VisualSVN setup.

My next question is how to access the SVN from a remote URL.  For instance, VisualSVN gives me 'https://PCNAME:PORT/svn' to navigate locally, but what about if I have a new developer that needs to access this from his own place?  I don't know how to access that remotely.

Comment: @JaredEitnier you'll need to set up a port forward on your router to make the svn port access ible from the outside world.  Then your remote developers can use http://YourRoutersPublicIpAddress:port/svn to access svn.  If you don't have a static IP address, and your IP changes often, this is likely to become annoying for your remote developers, so you might also want to consider a dynamic dns service like dyndns.org.